# New Lines Affecting Layout

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, newline

I'm adding DOM elements both via PHP and Javascript. They are exactly the same elements but somehow their outputs appear differently. To get a better picture, I'm providing a very simplified code below:

#### Javascript

```
var new_div = "<div>\
    <p>Hello</p>\
    </div>";

$(new_div).appendTo("#parent");
```

#### PHP

```
echo "<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
    </div>";
```

In PHP I'm not bothering to include new lines `\n` because I can write multiple lines of string just by writing on the next line. In Javascript however, I needed to escape new lines by using `\` or else I had to write the entire thing in one line.

When I loaded the page, both divs didn't look exactly the same. The output from Javascript looks like it has some extra margins where the newlines were supposed to be.

I can fix it by putting newlines `\n` on the PHP side. But I was hoping to keep the source codes cleaner and so I'm looking for a fix that only involves CSS if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `var new_div = "<div><p>Hello</p></div>";`?

Comment: @u_mulder It's definitely much much longer than that and having those in one line is a big nope. But thanks anyway. I'll try the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this instead

```
var new_div = "<div>";
new_div += "<p>Hello</p>";
new_div += "</div>";

$(new_div).appendTo("#parent");
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Can't believe I didn't think about it.